How to specify command line arguments to a Kotlin/Ktor app using ./gradlew?
I am building a standard Kotlin with Ktor application. I want to specify a different conf file in different situations. The documentation suggests how to do this by executing the jar directly.
This works for me:
$ ./gradlew installDir
$ ./build/install/my-api/bin/my-api -config=application-sandbox.conf

This does not:
$ ./gradlew run --args="-config=application-sandbox.conf"

My Application.kt and build.gradle.kts is mostly using the default stuff created by IntelliJ. I feel like this should be something basic and easy and that I'm probably just not realizing something obvious but how do I use a custom -config= value when executing with ./gradlew run?

Can you share the code of the main function? Also, please check that the application-sandbox.conf file does exist relative to the current working directory.
